# Horizontally align Chart.js y axes

Tags: javascript, css, chart.js

I have two (or more) Charts.js charts in my document. Since the y axes ticks aren't always the same width, the y axes are misaligned to each other.

[image]

html:

```
<body>
    <div class="mainContainer">
        <div class="mainSubContainer" id="main">
            <div class="graphContainer">
                <div class="graphHeader">Temperatur</div>
                <div class="graphElement"><canvas id="canvas1"></canvas></div>
            </div>
            <div class="graphContainer">
                <div class="graphHeader">relative Luftfeuchte</div>
                <div class="graphElement"><canvas id="canvas2"></canvas></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

My fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/1u7t6rfo/1/

Is there a way to align multiple Chart.js charts?

Answer (score 2):

You can set the width of the axis to be the same on both graphs

```
  scales: {
      yAxes: [
        {
          id: 'y-axis-1',
          afterUpdate: function(scale) {
            scale.width = 100 // Set this value to be the same on both graphs
          },
        },
      ],
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply set a max for the Y axes. E.g.

```
var maxY = 100;

....

scales: {
    yAxes: [{
        id: 'A',
        type: 'linear',
        ticks: {
            .....
            max: maxY
        },
    }]
    ....
}
```

here the snippet:

https://jsfiddle.net/Lx9unv47/

Also if you don't want to set the max of the Y axes manually you can do this:

```
var allValues = data.datasets[0].data.concat(data2.datasets[0].data);
var maxY = Math.max(...allValues);
```

and here the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/r6jgLmns/

Comment: not really a solution. The different y axis have nothing to do with each other and the ranges could be totally different.